# Server.MapPath not refreshing after changing the directory of an ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis

I have 2 ASP.NET applications. Let's say App1 and App2.

From App1, when I call Server.MapPath("/App2") I get the physical path of the App2 application.

When I change the path of App2 in IIS and I call Server.MapPath("/App2") again from App1, I get the same result.

I have to restart App1 for it to notice then change.

Is there something I can do about this without restarting App1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The calls to `Server.MapPath()` are likely being cached for performance, although there seems to be no documentation which alludes to this fact.

You can bypass this with the following code

**Disclaimer - This is a massive hack**, but it does the job

`Server.MapPath("/App2/" + Guid.NewGuid()).Substring(0,Server.MapPath("/App2/" + Guid.NewGuid()).Length-36)`

So yes, there is something you can do about this without restarting App1, but you probably will not want to do it.

Answer (score 0):

`Server.MapPath()` is reliant on the virtual path declared in IIS. There may be an internal IIS caching mechanism that delays your change from showing up without a restart of of your app, but I do not think there is any way to get changes to an IIS Virtual Directory to update without a restart.

Possibly try `HostingEnvironment.MapPath()` instead to see if that gets the correct path, but seeing as `Server.MapPath()` eventually calls `HostingEnvironment.MapPath()` anyway it may not be of much help.

Comment: Already tried HostingEnvironment.MapPath() and it's doing the thing.

Comment: Ok, worth a shot. In that case, I do not think there is any way to get changes to an IIS Virtual Directory to update without a restart.